# why isn't this centered? (Margin:0 auto; not working)

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm currently making a website (To be honest I'm not great at coding) but I've come across a problem, I've made my content div to a margin of 0 auto, which should place it in the center? But it's not working at the moment?

Website (To see the problem) : http://baileyiglesias.host56.com/home

CSS : http://baileyiglesias.host56.com/css/mainstyle.css

Thanks a bunch(:

-Bailey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you want:

```
#content {
    width: 900px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You could change the width to something else, like a % width, if you want it to be more flexible.

It's generally best not to set widths, min-widths etc. on the `body` element itself.

Answer (score 0):

after seeing you site I have seen this

```
body {
    min-width:900px;    
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

just change it to

```
body {
    width:900px;    
    height: 100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    background-color:#000;
}
```

you are not giving the width because of this `margin: 0 auto;` is not working

Comment: This just squishes the whole site up, all I want is the content in the middle to be centered.

Comment: so give the width to content and margin: 0 auto; value it will work

Answer (score 0):

add css for content div.

```
#content
{
  text-align: center;
}
```